# How to compare an html entity with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-entities

I have the following html code:

```
<h3 id="headerid"><span onclick="expandCollapse('headerid')">&uArr;</span>Header title</h3>
```

I would like to toggle between up arrow and down arrow each time the user clicks the span tag.

```
function expandCollapse(id) {   
    var arrow = $("#"+id+" span").html(); // I have tried with .text() too
    if(arrow == "&dArr;") {     
        $("#"+id+" span").html("&uArr;");               
    } else {        
        $("#"+id+" span").html("&dArr;");               
    }
}
```

My function is going always the else path. If I make a javacript:alert of `arrow` variable I am getting the html entity represented as an arrow. How can I tell jQuery to interpret the  `arrow` variable as a string and not as html.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When the HTML is parsed, what JQuery sees in the DOM is a `UPWARDS DOUBLE ARROW` ("⇑"), not the entity reference. Thus, in your Javascript code you should test for `"⇑"` or `"\u21d1"`. Also, you need to change what you're switching to:

```
function expandCollapse(id) {
    var arrow = $("#"+id+" span").html();
    if(arrow == "\u21d1") {     
        $("#"+id+" span").html("\u21d3");                           
    } else {            
        $("#"+id+" span").html("\u21d1");                           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do an alert of `arrow` what does it return? Does it return the exact string that you're matching against? If you are getting the actual characters `'⇓'` and `'⇑'` you may have to match it against `"\u21D1"` and `"\u21D3"`.

Also, you may want to try `&#8657;` and `&#8659;` since not all browsers support those entities.

**Update**: here's a fully working example:
http://jsbin.com/edogop/3/edit#html,live

```
window.expandCollapse = function (id) {   
  var $arrowSpan = $("#" + id + " span"),
      arrowCharCode = $arrowSpan.text().charCodeAt(0);

  // 8659 is the unicode value of the html entity
  if (arrowCharCode === 8659) {
    $arrowSpan.html("&#8657;");                           
  } else {            
    $arrowSpan.html("&#8659;");                           
  }

  // one liner:
  //$("#" + id + " span").html( ($("#" + id + " span").text().charCodeAt(0) === 8659) ? "&#8657;" : "&#8659;" );
};
```

Comment: When I look in an alert window I do see the single "up arrow". Is there any further discussion on this topic, the answers here haven't solved my issue which is identical to the original question.

Comment: See the update I've made with the working example. You'll want to update the 8657 & 8659 with the unicode values of the exact arrows that you're using.

Comment: Blam, that worked. Thanks. This feels like a hack, is there a reason why this is so tricky? BTW, I'm still pretty new to the stackoverflow community, so I apologize if all this discussion is inappropriate and should be moved to a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [.toggle()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle) effect.

Here is something similar i was playing with earlier.

HTML:

```
<div id="inplace">
<div id="myStatic">Hello World!</div>
<div id="myEdit" style="display: none">
<input id="myNewTxt" type="text" />
<input id="myOk" type="button" value="OK" />
<input id="myX" type="button" value="X" />
</div></div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 $("#myStatic").bind("click", function(){
      $("#myNewTxt").val($("#myStatic").text());
      $("#myStatic,#myEdit").toggle();
 });
 $("#myOk").click(function(){
      $("#myStatic").text($("#myNewTxt").val());
      $("#myStatic,#myEdit").toggle();
 });
 $("#myX").click(function(){
      $("#myStatic,#myEdit").toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a class to signal the current state of the span. 
The html could look like this

```
<h3 id="headerId"><span class="upArrow">&uArr;</span>Header title</h3>
```

Then in the javascript you do

```
$( '.upArrow, .downArrow' ).click( function( span ) {
    if ( span.hasClass( 'upArrow' ) )
        span.text( "&dArr;" );
    else
        span.text( "&uArr;" );
    span.toggleClass( 'upArrow' );
    span.toggleClass( 'downArrow' );
} );
```

This may not be the best way, but it should work. Didnt test it tough

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not getting an exact match because the browser is lower-casing the entity or something. Try using a carat (^) and lower-case "v" just for testing.

Edited - My first theory was plain wrong.