# jQuery issue with toggling HTML codes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check for the occurance of HTML decimal code and then switch accordingly, as per the Geometric Shapes [on this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes).

The code example is shown below, and the fiddle link is:

http://jsfiddle.net/w1sk6gsp/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( '.container' ).prepend( '<span class="HTML">&#9650;</span>' );
$( '.container' ).prepend( '<span class="Text">initial</span>' );

$( '.HTML' ).on( 'click', function() { 

    $( this ).html( $( this ).html() == '&#9650;' ? '&#9660;' : '&#9650;' );

} );

$( '.Text' ).on( 'click', function() { 

    $( this ).html( $( this ).html() == 'initial' ? 'switched' : 'initial' );

} ); 
});
```

I have included one called Text and one called HTML so you can see that it does work with text but not the HTML code, could anyone please explain how to get this to work and if not, at least the reasons why its not working.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003/how-to-compare-an-html-entity-with-jquery

Comment: And [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w1sk6gsp/7/)

Comment: You my friends, are absolute legends. Thanks so much!

Comment: Add an answer and have it accepted, so this question is not searchable under unanswered questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide an accepted answer so it doesn't show as unanswered the solution as provided by @Regent is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.container').prepend('<span class="HTML">&#9650;</span>');
   $('.container').prepend('<span class="Text">initial</span>');

   $('.HTML').on('click', function() {  
      $(this).html($(this).html() == '\u25B2' ? '&#9660;' : '&#9650;');
   });

   $('.Text').on('click', function() { 
      $(this).html($(this).html() == 'initial' ? 'switched' : 'initial' );
   }); 

});
```